# chown: invalid option -- 'i' Try 'chown --help' for more information

Tags: command-line, chown

I have a strange issue with the following command:

```
# chown -R myuser:mygroup *
chown: invalid option -- 'i'
Try 'chown --help' for more information.
```

the command is not aliases

```
# type chown
chown is hashed (/bin/chown)
```

Where I can look further?

Comment: You could try `chown -R myuser:mygroup ./*`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As the glob (pathname) expansion is done first by the shell before the `chown` runs, the glob pattern `*` is expanded to all files in the current directory first and `chown` is getting those as its options and arguments. You have a file in the current directory that starts with `-i`, hence `chown` is considering it as an option, not as an argument (filename).

You need to use `--` to indicate the end of options for `chown`:

```
chown -R myuser:mygroup -- *
```

Or precede the glob pattern (`*`) with `./` to explicitly indicate it as argument:

```
chown -R myuser:mygroup ./*
```

Comment: Prefixing with ./ doesn't mean that it's an argument (meaning filename here), but it does mean that none of the expanded names will look like an option (starting with "-"). When the shell sees a line like `chown -R myuser:mygroup ./*`, it splits it into `chown`, `-R`, `myuser:mygroup`, `./*` and then replaces glob patterns with the corresponding filesystem paths, eg. `chown`, `-R`, `myuser:mygroup`, `./-index.html`, `./favicon.ico`, `./My -ve Numbers`. Since chown only looks for the first character being a dash when looking for option args, it will presume that those are positional args.

Answer (score 7):

The issue was a file named `-index.php` in the folder, so chown interpreted it as a command line option.

The solution was using the double-hyphens `chown -R myuser:mygroup -- *`

Comment: isn't this the same answer already given by @heemayl?

Comment: @Kris both answers got posted at almost the same time ;-)

Comment: You obfuscated the user and group in your question but not in your answer...

Comment: @Kris It's rather unlikely he copied the other answer within 39 seconds after it was posed.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to imply such.